# Rails 5 Postgresql has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

in my app, I have 3 models here

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :specialties, class_name: "Specialty",
                        foreign_key:"teacher_id",
                        dependent: :destroy
 has_many :subjects, through: :specialties, source: :subject

class Specialty < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :subject, class_name: "Subject"

class Subject < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :teachers, through: :specialties, source: :teacher
 has_many :specialties, class_name: "Specialty",
                        foreign_key:"subject_id",
                        dependent: :destroy
```

In my rails console, previously when I was using SQLite I have no problems with 
`user = User.first` then `user.subjects` would return me all the user's subjects.
However after I have changed to PostgreSQL, it returns me

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...ects" INNER JOIN "specialties" ON "subjects"."id" = "special...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "subjects".* FROM "subjects" INNER JOIN "specialties" ON "subjects"."id" = "specialties"."subject_id" WHERE "specialties"."teacher_id" = $1
```

Is there any way I can do to return the user.subjects ?
I noticed that this problem did not occur when following rails tutorial model of following and followed. (The twitter model)

Thank you

edit, specialties is not an integer column , i shall change it and get back THanks alot !

Comment: `"specialties"."subject_id"` - is this an integer column ?

Comment: ohh it is not !  , i shall put that up after i get back from work . THanks!!

Comment: `t.string :subject_id` - It is **String** type, foreign keys should be of same type as your primary keys else you will get type cast error while comparing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error already gives hint:

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Postgresql is strict about type of columns being compared.

It looks you have foreign keys `subject_id` , `teacher_id` are of **string** type. So when you compare primary keys of type **integer** with foreign keys of type **string**, this error appears.

You can change column type to avoid this error:

```
change_column :specialties, :subject_id, :integer
change_column :specialties, :teacher_id, :integer
```

Comment: I'm looking for an alternate solution. Some of my models use primary keys that are strings, and some use integers. To allow for both, I've set my association_id column to be a string, but I'm running into this error.